# Any idea if this GPU (Asus DUAL-RTX2060-O6G-EVO) has dual DVI?

Tags: graphics-cards, compatibility, dvi

I have an old monitor with a dual DVI-D input and was wondering whether this card is compatible:
[Asus DUAL-RTX2060-O6G-EVO](https://www.asus.com/Motherboards-Components/Graphics-Cards/Dual/DUAL-RTX2060-O6G-EVO/techspec/)

I can see that it has the right DVI-D (digital) port, and that its maximum resolution is way above 1080p, but is doesn't explicitly say if the DVI-D port outputs dual DVI (my monitor's native is 2560x1600)

Comment: I can't answer with 100% certainty but the photos of the card show the DVI port accepts all of the pins for DVI-D **Dual Link**. Pretty much every GPU in the past 10 years with a DVI port has supported Dual Link and at this point it isn't a premium feature, it's pretty much the standard for DVI. It would be a surprise to see Single Link on any RTX2060.

Comment: @Romen you are right, I found it misleading to find out that having the dual link DVI-D port (all the 24 pins) it is, in fact, single link... (directly from ASUS support)

Comment: You can get an adapter to convert from DisplayPort to Dual-Link DVI anyway. Only a minor inconvenience but they are more expensive than the usual adapters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question:

From ASUS support chat: it does not support dual link DVI.

Comment: I believe the question is asking about dual-link DVI, not whether the GPU has two DVI ports.

Comment: hi @Romen, you are right, I was asking about dual-link and the answer above is my own, directly from ASUS support

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice it was you in both the Q & A. I was just confused by your use of the term "dual DVI" because many previous generation of GPUs actually have 2 DVI ports too. Your edit clears everything up!